# Best design pattern to handle action oriented requirement

Tags: c#, design-patterns, workflow, action

I have an entity `Order` with a `Status` property. Status will be Enum’s like New, Processed, Disable..etc. I have set of Actions like, DeleteOrder, DuplicateOrder..etc.

Actions will be available based on status. I need to get list of Actions when I pass Instance of Order to a method. How can I achieve this. I have following pattern.

```
public class Order (entity)
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public OrderStatus Status { get; set; }
}

public enum OrderStatus
{
   New,
   Processed,
   Disable
} 

public class OrderActionModel 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public OrderAction Action { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
}

public enum OrderAction
{
   DeleteOrder,
   DuplicateOrder
} 

public interface IAction
{
    void Process();
}

public interface IActionFactory
{
    IAction GetAction(OrderActionModel model);
    List<string> GetActions(Order order);
}

public class ActionFactory : IActionFactory
{
    private readonly IMailService _mailService;

    public ActionFactory(IMailService mailService)
    {
        _mailService = mailService;
    }

    public IAction GetAction(OrderActionModel model)
    {
        switch (model.Action)
        {
            case DeleteOrder:
                    return new DeleteOrderAction(model, _mailService);
            case DuplicateOrder:
                    return new DuplicateOrderAction(model, _mailService);
            default:
                    return null;
        }
    }

    public List<string> GetActions(Order order)
    {
        //How to call isValidAction from here for each list of actions
    }
}

public class DeleteOrderAction : IAction
{
    private OrderActionModel _model;
    private readonly IMailService _mailService;

    public DeleteOrderAction(OrderActionModel model, IMailService  mailService)
    {
         _model = model;
         _repository = repository;
    }

    public void Process()
    {
        AddAudit(_model.comments);
        SendEMail();
    }

    public bool IsValidAction(Order order)
    {
         return order.Status == OrderStatus.New;
    }
}

public IHttpActionResult Action(OrderActionModel model)
{
    IAction action = _actionFactory.GetAction(model);         
    action.Process();
    return Ok();
}

public IHttpActionResult GetActions(1)
{
    //get order by id
    var order = repo.getOrder(1)
    //Some method to get Actions
    var actions = SampleMethod(order)
    return Ok(actions);
}
```

Comment: That switch-case in `public IHttpActionResult Action` is completely redundant.

Comment: You need to show more of your structures, in particular the models you're using. It seems really messy, `Order`, `OrderActionModel`, `OrderModel`, there are so many types and it's hard to tell the difference. Also, is `OrderStatus` the way you decide wether the `IAction` is valid? There needs to be a clear 1-1 mapping between something with `Order` and the viable actions. It'd probably make sense to have actual _types_ of `Orders`, but again, more info on your class hierarchy is needed.

Comment: @V0ldek Added details of Order, OrderActionModel

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to stick with this model, the simplest way to achieve what you want would be

```
Dictionary<string, Func<Order, bool>> actionNameToViableCheck;
```

You put your actions along with their related validation functions during app initialization, so

```
actionNameToViableCheck.Add("Delete Order", o => DeleteOrderAction.IsValidOrder(o));
```

This requires the `IsValidOrder` method to be `static`.

Then your `GetActions` could look something like this:

```
public List<string> GetActions(Order order) => 
    actionNameToViableCheck.Where(kv => kv.Value(order)).Select(kv => kv.Key);
```

Note that this is not the most effective solution if there are many different actions, because you process all of them every time. But since you define validity of an Action by its `IsValidOrder` method output, I don't see a much better simple way.

Comment: @VOIdek Thank for your solution. I ll try this.

Comment: If this helped, consider accepting the answer so the question is "closed".